# What is the difference between async await and async_hooks in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-2017, async-hooks

[async_hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) were introduced as experimental in Node v8. Because the name is similar to ES2017 [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) it could appear that they may be in some way related. Are they? If so, in what way (complementary or competing)?

Comment: Very interesting. Seems to be used for traking async call state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[async_hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) API makes it easier for you to track your resources. You start off by initializing it with an optional object of any of: `init`, `before`, `after` and `destroy`. Getting a resource triggers one of these callbacks. The point of `async_hooks` is to allow a better tracking of asynchronous resources and their callbacks.

`async await` Lets you write code which has promise based asynchronous parts in it in a more familiar synchronous looking way.

For example:

```
async function Double() {
  let result = await PromiseWhichReturnsNumber();

  return result * 2;
}
```

In the above `async` function the function will pause execution at `PromiseWhichReturnsNumber()` until the promise is resolved (and the results are assigned to `result`).

The 2 concepts are solving different issues:

1. `async await` lets you write promises in a "synchronous" way.
2. `async_hooks` allows you to track async resources.